# How to fix MaterializeCSS vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, grid, materialize

I'm creating a new project and I'm using MaterializeCSS. I've got a problem with element when they are in Small Column. Element is alone on a line but it should not be here (see picture) and it happens when window is resized (not every time, it depends on of the width)

Here is an image to show you

[image]

My code is basic, not modify Materialize library. It looks like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s6"></div>
    <div class="col s3"></div>
    <div class="col s3"></div>
    <div class="col s3"></div>
    <div class="col s3"></div>
    <div class="col s4"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: can you place the full code as a snippet

Answer (score 0):

According to materialize css they have media queries for only 3 standard devices small large and medium. If your template is working good at these three standards and you still want it to work accurately on other screen sizes (e.g in between these standard sizes) then you should go with declaring your own media queries.

Note: if you resize the screen and reload the page after that and your template looks fine then it's not something to worry about.

Your question is still not very clear.

Comment: I'm trying to make a grid like this : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/07/5/1550237643-test.png

But when window is resized, this happend : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/07/5/1550237643-test2.png

I use S, M  and L from  materialize, but this thing happening :(

I think it's because of % value grid but not sure

Comment: is it happening even after you reload the page after resizing?

Comment: Yes it is, don't know why :(

Comment: @Lucas https://jsfiddle.net/bilalkhan891/bf0jtqLk/15/ here i have tried the same grids as shown in your picture but it seems like you have some problem with your code.

Comment: Thanks for your time ! It seams to be somewhere else tho